# how to delete AWS RDS public snapshots

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

How can I delete this Amazon RDS public snapshot?

[image]

[image]

Comment: looks like you don't have the right permissions. Who is the user that set up the RDS and snapshot/backup policy? Using that account you will be able to delete these public snapshots.

Comment: If the public snapshot belongs to your account, you should be able to delete it, but if it doesn't belong to your account, you cant delete it, just like the public AMIs. The error in the second screenshot is related to this. You are probably trying to delete the public snapshot that is not owned by your account.

Comment: If you are not the owner of the original snapshot, you can't delete it.

Comment: Before submitting a question, try implementing the instructions given as part of an error message.